# Generic Type with namespace restriction

Tags: c#, generics

Everyone knows

```
public class Test<T> where T : SomeBaseClass
```

But is there a way to restrict `T` to classes that exists in a namespace like

```
public class Test<T> where T in SomeNamespace
```

Best regards

Comment: Namespaces are just names, they do not contribute to the contract of the type (in contrast to inheritance or interface implementations). Generic type constraints are about contract assumptions, therefore their namespaces are irrelevant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. There's no way to constrain a generic type to a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Namespace constrains are not possible. Anyway it does not makes any sence because everyone can create classes which are located in the target namespace. It maybe would only make sence if you can restrict it to a specific assembly.

Would make more sence if you can restrict it to `n` types like the following lines( doesn't work ):

```
public T Create<T>() where T : { MyClass1, MyClass2 }
```

#### See constraints

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No. Constraints are about specifying behaviour - whether that is as simple as being a class, implementing a given interface or whatever. It's *not* about which namespace a class is defined in - that says nothing about its behaviour.

See [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for a constraint summary

Answer (score 0):

You could sort of do this by creating an interface with internal scope and using that in your generic where clause (generic class/method would need to be in the same assembly).  Then you would only be able to use it with classes in the same assembly that implement that interface.

If you needed to pass classes from another assembly, you could add a global::InternalsVisibleToAttribute('other assemblys name') to the AssemblyInfo file.

All that being said, it still doesn't sound like the sort of thing to try and achieve.

Comment: Actually, ignore that, you could just make your generic method internal.